# BERT always predicts same class (Fine-Tuning)

Tags: python, machine-learning, pytorch, huggingface-transformers, simpletransformers

I am fine-tuning BERT on a financial news dataset.
Unfortunately BERT seems to be trapped in a local minimum. It is content with learning to always predict the same class.

- balancing the dataset didnt work
- tuning parameters didnt work as well

I am honestly not sure what is causing this problem. With the simpletransformers library I am getting very good results. I would really appreciate if somebody could help me. thanks a lot!

Full code on github:
https://github.com/Bene939/BERT_News_Sentiment_Classifier

Code:

```
from transformers import BertForSequenceClassification, AdamW, BertTokenizer, get_linear_schedule_with_warmup, Trainer, TrainingArguments
import torch
from torch.utils.data import DataLoader, RandomSampler, SequentialSampler, TensorDataset
import pandas as pd
from pathlib import Path
import sklearn
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score, precision_recall_fscore_support
import numpy as np
from torch.nn import functional as F
from collections import defaultdict
import random


#defining tokenizer, model and optimizer
tokenizer = BertTokenizer.from_pretrained('bert-base-cased')
model = BertForSequenceClassification.from_pretrained('bert-base-cased', num_labels=3)


if torch.cuda.is_available():
  print("\nUsing: ", torch.cuda.get_device_name(0))
  device = torch.device('cuda')
else:
  print("\nUsing: CPU")
  device = torch.device('cpu')
model = model.to(device)


#loading dataset
labeled_dataset = "news_headlines_sentiment.csv"
labeled_dataset_file = Path(labeled_dataset)
file_loaded = False
while not file_loaded:
  if labeled_dataset_file.exists():
    labeled_dataset = pd.read_csv(labeled_dataset_file)
    file_loaded = True
    print("Dataset Loaded")
  else:
    print("File not Found")
print(labeled_dataset)

#counting sentiments
negative = 0
neutral = 0
positive = 0
for idx, row in labeled_dataset.iterrows():
  if row["sentiment"] == 0:
    negative += 1
  elif row["sentiment"] == 1:
    neutral += 1
  else:
    positive += 1
print("Unbalanced Dataset")
print("negative: ", negative)
print("neutral: ", neutral)
print("positive: ", positive)

#balancing dataset to 1/3 per sentiment
for idx, row in labeled_dataset.iterrows():
  if row["sentiment"] == 0:
    if negative - neutral != 0:
      index_name = labeled_dataset[labeled_dataset["news"] == row["news"]].index
      labeled_dataset.drop(index_name, inplace=True)
      negative -= 1
  elif row["sentiment"] == 2:
    if positive - neutral != 0:
      index_name = labeled_dataset[labeled_dataset["news"] == row["news"]].index
      labeled_dataset.drop(index_name, inplace=True)
      positive -= 1

#custom dataset class
class NewsSentimentDataset(torch.utils.data.Dataset):
  def __init__(self, encodings, labels):
        self.encodings = encodings
        self.labels = labels

  def __getitem__(self, idx):
      item = {key: torch.tensor(val[idx]) for key, val in self.encodings.items()}
      item['labels'] = torch.tensor(self.labels[idx])
      return item

  def __len__(self):
      return len(self.labels)

#method for tokenizing dataset list
def tokenize_headlines(headlines, labels, tokenizer):

  encodings = tokenizer.batch_encode_plus(
      headlines,
      add_special_tokens = True,
      truncation = True,
      padding = 'max_length',
      return_attention_mask = True,
      return_token_type_ids = True
  )

  dataset = NewsSentimentDataset(encodings, labels)
  return dataset

#splitting dataset into training and validation set
#load news sentiment dataset
all_headlines = labeled_dataset['news'].tolist()
all_labels = labeled_dataset['sentiment'].tolist()

train_headlines, val_headlines, train_labels, val_labels = train_test_split(all_headlines, all_labels, test_size=.2)

val_dataset = tokenize_headlines(val_headlines, val_labels, tokenizer)
train_dataset = tokenize_headlines(train_headlines, val_labels, tokenizer)

#data loader
train_batch_size = 8
val_batch_size = 8

train_data_loader = DataLoader(train_dataset, batch_size = train_batch_size, shuffle=True)
val_data_loader = DataLoader(val_dataset, batch_size = val_batch_size, sampler=SequentialSampler(val_dataset))

#optimizer and scheduler
num_epochs = 1
num_steps = len(train_data_loader) * num_epochs
optimizer = AdamW(model.parameters(), lr=5e-5, eps=1e-8)
scheduler = get_linear_schedule_with_warmup(optimizer, num_warmup_steps=num_steps*0.06, num_training_steps=num_steps)

#training and evaluation
seed_val = 64

random.seed(seed_val)
np.random.seed(seed_val)
torch.manual_seed(seed_val)
torch.cuda.manual_seed_all(seed_val)

for epoch in range(num_epochs):

  print("\n###################################################")
  print("Epoch: {}/{}".format(epoch+1, num_epochs))
  print("###################################################\n")

  #training phase
 
  average_train_loss = 0
  average_train_acc = 0
  model.train() 
  for step, batch in enumerate(train_data_loader):
      
      
      input_ids = batch['input_ids'].to(device)
      attention_mask = batch['attention_mask'].to(device)
      labels = batch['labels'].to(device)
      token_type_ids = batch['token_type_ids'].to(device)


      outputs = model(input_ids=input_ids, attention_mask=attention_mask, token_type_ids = token_type_ids)

      loss = F.cross_entropy(outputs[0], labels)
      average_train_loss += loss

      if step % 40 == 0:
        print("Training Loss: ", loss)

      logits = outputs[0].detach().cpu().numpy()
      label_ids = labels.to('cpu').numpy()

      average_train_acc += sklearn.metrics.accuracy_score(label_ids, np.argmax(logits, axis=1))
      print("predictions: ",np.argmax(logits, axis=1))
      print("labels:      ",label_ids)
      print("#############")
      optimizer.zero_grad()
      loss.backward()
      #maximum gradient clipping
      torch.nn.utils.clip_grad_norm_(model.parameters(), 1.0)
      
      optimizer.step()
      scheduler.step()
      model.zero_grad()

  average_train_loss = average_train_loss / len(train_data_loader)
  average_train_acc = average_train_acc / len(train_data_loader)
  print("======Average Training Loss: {:.5f}======".format(average_train_loss))
  print("======Average Training Accuracy: {:.2f}%======".format(average_train_acc*100))

  #validation phase
  average_val_loss = 0
  average_val_acc = 0
  model.eval()
  for step,batch in enumerate(val_data_loader):
    input_ids = batch['input_ids'].to(device)
    attention_mask = batch['attention_mask'].to(device)
    labels = batch['labels'].to(device)
    token_type_ids = batch['token_type_ids'].to(device)

    pred = []
    with torch.no_grad():
      

      outputs = model(input_ids=input_ids, attention_mask=attention_mask, token_type_ids=token_type_ids)

      loss = F.cross_entropy(outputs[0], labels)
      average_val_loss += loss

      logits = outputs[0].detach().cpu().numpy()
      label_ids = labels.to('cpu').numpy()
      print("predictions: ",np.argmax(logits, axis=1))
      print("labels:      ",label_ids)
      print("#############")

      average_val_acc += sklearn.metrics.accuracy_score(label_ids, np.argmax(logits, axis=1))

  average_val_loss = average_val_loss / len(val_data_loader)
  average_val_acc = average_val_acc / len(val_data_loader)

  print("======Average Validation Loss: {:.5f}======".format(average_val_loss))
  print("======Average Validation Accuracy: {:.2f}%======".format(average_val_acc*100))
###################################################
Epoch: 1/1
###################################################

Training Loss:  tensor(1.1006, device='cuda:0', grad_fn=<NllLossBackward>)
predictions:  [1 0 2 0 0 0 2 0]
labels:       [2 0 1 1 0 1 0 1]
#############
predictions:  [2 2 0 0 0 2 0 0]
labels:       [1 2 1 0 2 0 1 2]
#############
predictions:  [0 0 0 0 1 0 0 1]
labels:       [0 1 1 0 1 1 2 0]
#############
predictions:  [0 0 0 2 0 1 0 0]
labels:       [0 0 0 2 0 0 2 1]
#############
predictions:  [1 0 0 0 0 0 2 0]
labels:       [0 2 2 1 0 0 0 0]
#############
predictions:  [0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0]
labels:       [1 0 2 2 2 1 1 1]
#############
predictions:  [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
labels:       [2 2 2 2 2 0 2 0]
#############
predictions:  [0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0]
labels:       [2 2 0 2 0 0 0 1]
#############
predictions:  [0 0 0 0 0 2 0 1]
labels:       [0 1 0 2 2 0 1 2]
#############
predictions:  [0 0 2 0 0 0 1 0]
labels:       [0 0 0 1 2 1 1 1]
#############
predictions:  [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
labels:       [0 2 1 0 1 0 1 1]
#############
predictions:  [0 2 0 0 0 0 0 0]
labels:       [2 2 0 1 0 1 2 1]
#############
predictions:  [0 1 0 0 0 0 1 2]
labels:       [2 2 1 0 2 0 0 2]
#############
predictions:  [0 0 1 1 1 1 0 1]
labels:       [1 2 1 1 1 1 2 2]
#############
predictions:  [1 0 0 0 0 1 2 1]
labels:       [1 0 1 1 0 0 0 2]
#############
predictions:  [0 1 1 1 1 0 2 1]
labels:       [2 2 1 2 2 1 1 2]
#############
predictions:  [0 0 1 0 1 1 0 0]
labels:       [1 0 0 1 0 1 0 2]
#############
predictions:  [1 2 0 0 1 2 0 0]
labels:       [0 2 2 1 2 0 1 0]
#############
predictions:  [0 2 1 1 0 1 1 0]
labels:       [2 2 0 1 1 0 1 2]
#############
predictions:  [1 0 1 1 1 1 1 0]
labels:       [0 2 0 1 0 1 2 2]
#############
predictions:  [0 2 1 2 0 0 1 1]
labels:       [2 1 1 1 1 2 2 0]
#############
predictions:  [0 1 2 2 2 1 1 2]
labels:       [2 2 1 1 2 1 0 1]
#############
predictions:  [2 2 2 1 2 1 1 1]
labels:       [0 1 1 0 0 2 2 1]
#############
predictions:  [1 2 2 2 1 2 1 2]
labels:       [0 0 0 0 2 0 1 2]
#############
predictions:  [2 1 1 1 2 2 2 2]
labels:       [1 0 2 2 1 0 0 0]
#############
predictions:  [2 1 2 2 2 1 2 2]
labels:       [2 1 1 1 1 1 2 2]
#############
predictions:  [1 1 0 2 1 2 1 2]
labels:       [2 2 0 2 0 1 2 0]
#############
predictions:  [0 1 1 2 0 1 2 1]
labels:       [2 2 2 1 2 2 0 1]
#############
predictions:  [2 1 1 1 1 2 1 1]
labels:       [0 1 1 2 1 0 0 2]
#############
predictions:  [1 2 2 0 1 1 1 2]
labels:       [0 1 2 1 2 1 0 1]
#############
predictions:  [0 1 1 1 1 1 1 0]
labels:       [0 2 0 1 1 2 2 2]
#############
predictions:  [1 2 1 1 2 1 1 0]
labels:       [0 2 2 2 0 0 1 0]
#############
predictions:  [2 2 2 1 2 1 1 2]
labels:       [2 2 1 2 1 0 0 0]
#############
predictions:  [2 2 1 2 2 2 1 2]
labels:       [1 1 2 2 2 0 2 1]
#############
predictions:  [2 2 2 2 2 0 2 2]
labels:       [2 2 1 2 0 1 1 2]
#############
predictions:  [1 1 2 1 2 2 0 1]
labels:       [2 1 1 1 0 0 2 2]
#############
predictions:  [2 1 2 2 2 2 1 0]
labels:       [0 2 0 2 0 0 0 0]
#############
predictions:  [2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2]
labels:       [1 1 0 2 0 1 2 1]
#############
predictions:  [2 2 2 2 1 2 2 2]
labels:       [1 0 0 1 1 0 0 0]
#############
predictions:  [2 2 2 1 2 2 2 2]
labels:       [1 0 1 1 0 2 2 0]
#############
Training Loss:  tensor(1.1104, device='cuda:0', grad_fn=<NllLossBackward>)
predictions:  [2 0 1 2 1 2 2 0]
labels:       [2 2 0 0 1 0 0 2]
#############
predictions:  [0 2 2 0 2 1 1 1]
labels:       [0 0 0 1 0 0 1 0]
#############
predictions:  [0 2 2 0 1 1 1 2]
labels:       [2 1 1 1 2 2 1 0]
#############
predictions:  [2 1 1 2 2 0 2 0]
labels:       [1 2 1 2 1 0 2 1]
#############
predictions:  [0 2 2 0 0 2 1 2]
labels:       [0 0 2 2 0 0 2 0]
#############
predictions:  [0 0 1 2 2 0 2 2]
labels:       [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
#############
predictions:  [1 1 2 1 2 0 1 2]
labels:       [0 0 2 0 0 0 1 1]
#############
predictions:  [0 0 2 1 0 2 0 1]
labels:       [1 1 2 1 1 0 2 0]
#############
predictions:  [0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0]
labels:       [2 2 1 1 2 1 1 1]
#############
predictions:  [0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0]
labels:       [1 1 2 2 1 1 2 0]
#############
predictions:  [0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1]
labels:       [2 0 1 1 0 1 2 2]
#############
predictions:  [0 0 1 0 0 1 2 1]
labels:       [1 2 0 2 2 0 2 1]
#############
predictions:  [1 1 1 1 0 1 0 1]
labels:       [2 0 1 0 1 0 1 2]
#############
predictions:  [1 2 2 0 0 0 1 1]
labels:       [2 0 0 2 1 2 2 2]
#############
predictions:  [1 0 2 1 0 2 2 0]
labels:       [0 0 2 1 2 1 1 1]
#############
predictions:  [0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1]
labels:       [1 2 1 0 0 0 1 0]
#############
predictions:  [1 1 1 0 1 1 0 1]
labels:       [0 2 1 2 1 2 2 0]
#############
predictions:  [2 1 0 1 1 2 0 0]
labels:       [0 1 0 0 1 2 0 2]
#############
predictions:  [0 1 1 0 0 1 0 1]
labels:       [1 0 0 2 2 1 1 2]
#############
predictions:  [1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1]
labels:       [2 0 1 0 2 0 0 2]
#############
predictions:  [1 0 0 1 0 1 0 2]
labels:       [1 0 0 1 1 2 2 1]
#############
predictions:  [1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0]
labels:       [1 1 0 2 1 0 2 0]
#############
predictions:  [1 1 2 1 0 1 0 0]
labels:       [0 2 1 2 1 1 0 2]
#############
predictions:  [1 1 0 0 1 2 1 1]
labels:       [0 2 1 0 2 2 0 1]
#############
predictions:  [0 1 1 0 0 1 0 1]
labels:       [0 0 1 2 2 0 1 2]
#############
predictions:  [1 0 2 2 2 1 1 0]
labels:       [2 2 1 0 0 1 1 2]
#############
predictions:  [1 2 2 1 1 2 1 1]
labels:       [1 0 0 1 0 0 0 0]
#############
predictions:  [0 2 0 2 2 0 2 2]
labels:       [2 0 0 0 2 1 1 2]
#############
predictions:  [0 0 1 0 1 0 2 2]
labels:       [0 0 1 0 1 0 2 0]
#############
predictions:  [0 2 0 1 1 2 2 0]
labels:       [0 2 0 2 0 2 0 0]
#############
predictions:  [2 2 2 2 2 2 2 1]
labels:       [2 2 1 1 0 0 2 2]
#############
predictions:  [2 0 0 2 2 1 1 0]
labels:       [1 0 0 1 0 2 1 2]
#############
predictions:  [2 0 0 2 0 2 2 0]
labels:       [2 2 2 2 0 1 1 1]
#############
predictions:  [0 2 2 0 2 2 0 0]
labels:       [1 0 1 2 0 1 1 1]
#############
predictions:  [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 2]
labels:       [2 1 1 0 0 0 1 2]
#############
predictions:  [2 0 2 0 2 1 0 2]
labels:       [2 1 1 2 1 1 0 0]
#############
predictions:  [1 1 2 0 2 0 2 2]
labels:       [0 2 1 2 1 2 1 0]
#############
predictions:  [2 0 1 1 0 2 0 0]
labels:       [2 1 0 1 1 0 2 0]
#############
predictions:  [2 0 0 2 0 2 1 0]
labels:       [0 0 0 0 2 1 0 1]
#############
predictions:  [1 2 1 0 0 2 0 2]
labels:       [2 0 2 1 0 0 1 1]
#############
Training Loss:  tensor(1.1162, device='cuda:0', grad_fn=<NllLossBackward>)
predictions:  [2 0 0 1 1 1 0 1]
labels:       [0 1 1 1 1 2 2 1]
#############
predictions:  [0 2 0 1 2 0 0 1]
labels:       [2 2 1 0 1 0 0 0]
#############
predictions:  [0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1]
labels:       [1 0 2 0 0 2 2 0]
#############
predictions:  [2 1 2 2 0 1 2 0]
labels:       [2 0 1 0 2 1 0 1]
#############
predictions:  [1 0 0 2 0 0 1 1]
labels:       [2 2 0 2 0 2 0 0]
#############
predictions:  [0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0]
labels:       [2 2 2 1 2 2 2 2]
#############
predictions:  [0 0 1 1 0 1 1 0]
labels:       [2 1 1 1 0 2 1 0]
#############
predictions:  [0 0 0 1 0 0 1 0]
labels:       [2 0 2 2 0 0 1 2]
#############
predictions:  [1 0 1 0 0 2 0 0]
labels:       [1 1 2 0 0 1 0 0]
#############
predictions:  [2 1 0 0 0 1 0 0]
labels:       [1 2 0 0 0 0 0 0]
#############
predictions:  [0 2 0 0 0 0 0 0]
labels:       [2 0 1 1 2 2 1 1]
#############
predictions:  [0 1 0 0 0 1 0 2]
labels:       [0 2 1 1 0 0 1 2]
#############
predictions:  [0 2 1 0 0 1 1 1]
labels:       [1 1 0 2 0 1 1 0]
#############
predictions:  [0 1 1 0 0 0 1 0]
labels:       [0 0 1 0 1 2 1 1]
#############
predictions:  [0 1 1 0 1 0 0 0]
labels:       [0 1 1 1 2 2 2 0]
#############
predictions:  [0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0]
labels:       [2 0 2 2 1 2 2 2]
#############
predictions:  [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
labels:       [2 2 0 2 2 0 1 1]
#############
predictions:  [0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0]
labels:       [0 2 0 1 1 2 0 2]
#############
predictions:  [1 1 0 1 0 1 0 2]
labels:       [1 2 0 0 2 2 2 1]
#############
predictions:  [1 1 0 0 0 1 2 1]
labels:       [0 0 1 2 2 1 2 2]
#############
predictions:  [1 1 1 0 1 1 2 0]
labels:       [0 0 0 2 0 1 0 2]
#############
predictions:  [0 1 0 0 1 1 2 1]
labels:       [2 0 0 1 2 2 1 2]
#############
predictions:  [1 0 0 0 1 0 0 1]
labels:       [1 2 2 2 2 1 0 1]
#############
predictions:  [2 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
labels:       [1 2 0 2 2 1 1 1]
#############
predictions:  [2 0 1 1 0 0 1 0]
labels:       [0 0 0 0 2 2 1 1]
#############
predictions:  [2 0 0 1 0 0 1 1]
labels:       [2 2 1 1 0 0 1 0]
#############
predictions:  [1 1 1 1 1 2 0 0]
labels:       [0 0 2 1 0 0 0 0]
#############
predictions:  [1 1 2 0 1 2 0 1]
labels:       [0 2 1 0 2 0 0 1]
#############
predictions:  [0 0 2 1 0 2 0 1]
labels:       [1 2 0 2 2 1 0 0]
#############
predictions:  [0 0 2 0 2 1 1 2]
labels:       [2 2 1 2 2 2 0 0]
#############
predictions:  [0 1 0 0 0 0 2 1]
labels:       [1 1 0 1 1 1 0 1]
#############
predictions:  [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
labels:       [0 1 0 0 2 0 0 2]
#############
predictions:  [2 2 2 0 1 1 1 0]
labels:       [1 0 2 1 1 2 0 0]
#############
predictions:  [0 0 1 0 0 0 2 0]
labels:       [0 1 2 1 1 0 0 0]
#############
predictions:  [0 2 0 1 0 2 0 0]
labels:       [0 0 2 1 1 0 2 2]
#############
predictions:  [0 0 1 2 0 2 0 1]
labels:       [2 2 0 0 0 2 2 2]
#############
predictions:  [1 0 0 0 2 0 0 1]
labels:       [2 0 1 1 1 0 0 1]
#############
predictions:  [0 1 0 0 0 0 0 2]
labels:       [1 1 1 0 0 0 2 2]
#############
predictions:  [0 2 0 1 0 2 0 0]
labels:       [1 1 1 1 2 2 1 0]
#############
predictions:  [1 2 0 0 0 0 0 0]
labels:       [2 0 2 1 0 1 1 1]
#############
Training Loss:  tensor(1.2082, device='cuda:0', grad_fn=<NllLossBackward>)
predictions:  [0 2 0 0 0 0 2 0]
labels:       [1 0 2 1 2 2 1 1]
#############
predictions:  [2 0 0 0 0 0 1 0]
labels:       [1 0 0 0 0 2 1 0]
#############
predictions:  [0 0 0 0 2 1 1 1]
labels:       [0 2 2 0 1 2 1 1]
#############
predictions:  [2 1 0 1 0 0 2 0]
labels:       [1 0 2 1 0 2 1 0]
#############
predictions:  [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
labels:       [0 1 0 0 0 0 1 0]
#############
predictions:  [0 2 1 0 0 0 1 1]
labels:       [0 2 2 2 2 1 1 0]
#############
predictions:  [0 0 0 1 1 0 0 1]
labels:       [0 1 0 1 2 2 2 2]
#############
predictions:  [0 0 0 1 1 1 1 2]
labels:       [2 2 1 2 0 1 1 1]
#############
predictions:  [0 1 2 0 0 1 0 0]
labels:       [0 2 1 0 0 1 0 0]
#############
predictions:  [1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0]
labels:       [2 1 2 1 0 2 2 1]
#############
predictions:  [0 1 2 0 0 1 1 0]
labels:       [2 0 2 1 1 1 2 1]
#############
predictions:  [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
labels:       [0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0]
#############
predictions:  [0 0 0 0 0 1 2 2]
labels:       [2 2 1 1 0 2 1 2]
#############
predictions:  [0 1 0 0 1 1 0 1]
labels:       [0 1 0 2 1 0 0 1]
#############
predictions:  [0 2 2 0 0 0 0 2]
labels:       [0 0 2 1 2 2 0 1]
#############
predictions:  [2 0 0 2 2 0 2 0]
labels:       [2 1 0 2 2 0 1 0]
#############
predictions:  [0 2 2 0 2 1 1 2]
labels:       [1 1 0 0 2 1 0 0]
#############
predictions:  [1 1 2 2 0 0 1 2]
labels:       [2 0 2 0 1 1 1 1]
#############
predictions:  [0 1 1 0 0 1 1 0]
labels:       [0 2 1 0 0 2 2 0]
#############
predictions:  [2 1 0 0 0 0 1 1]
labels:       [0 2 0 2 0 0 1 1]
#############
predictions:  [1 2 0 1 2 0 0 0]
labels:       [1 0 1 1 0 2 2 2]
#############
predictions:  [0 0 0 0 2 2 1 2]
labels:       [2 2 2 1 1 1 1 0]
#############
predictions:  [1 2 0 1 0 0 2 0]
labels:       [2 2 1 1 1 0 2 0]
#############
predictions:  [2 0 0 0 0 2 1]
labels:       [0 1 1 2 2 0 2]
#############
======Average Training Loss: 1.11279======
======Average Training Accuracy: 33.77%======
predictions:  [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
labels:       [0 2 0 1 1 0 1 0]
#############
predictions:  [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
labels:       [2 1 0 2 1 0 0 0]
#############
predictions:  [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
labels:       [1 2 2 2 1 2 0 2]
#############
predictions:  [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
labels:       [2 1 1 2 0 1 2 0]
#############
predictions:  [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
labels:       [2 0 2 0 0 1 2 0]
#############
predictions:  [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
labels:       [1 1 0 1 2 1 0 1]
#############
predictions:  [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
labels:       [1 2 1 2 0 2 1 0]
#############
predictions:  [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
labels:       [2 2 1 2 2 1 1 1]
#############
predictions:  [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
labels:       [1 1 0 2 2 0 0 2]
#############
predictions:  [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
labels:       [0 0 0 0 2 0 1 2]
#############
predictions:  [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
labels:       [1 1 0 1 1 2 1 2]
#############
predictions:  [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
labels:       [0 1 1 2 2 0 2 0]
#############
predictions:  [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
labels:       [2 0 0 0 1 2 2 1]
#############
predictions:  [0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0]
labels:       [0 0 1 1 0 2 0 0]
#############
predictions:  [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
labels:       [1 0 1 2 2 0 1 0]
#############
predictions:  [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
labels:       [2 1 1 2 2 2 0 2]
#############
predictions:  [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
labels:       [1 0 2 1 2 0 0 1]
#############
predictions:  [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
labels:       [2 0 0 0 2 2 0 2]
#############
predictions:  [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
labels:       [1 1 1 0 1 0 1 1]
#############
predictions:  [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
labels:       [0 2 2 2 2 2 1 1]
#############
predictions:  [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
labels:       [0 0 2 1 1 0 2 0]
#############
predictions:  [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
labels:       [1 2 1 1 2 0 0 0]
#############
predictions:  [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
labels:       [2 2 2 1 2 2 0 2]
#############
predictions:  [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
labels:       [0 2 0 1 0 2 0 1]
#############
predictions:  [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
labels:       [1 0 1 2 1 1 0 2]
#############
predictions:  [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
labels:       [1 0 0 1 2 1 1 1]
#############
predictions:  [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
labels:       [1 1 1 1 1 0 1 0]
#############
predictions:  [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
labels:       [2 2 1 0 0 2 2 2]
#############
predictions:  [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
labels:       [1 1 1 0 0 0 2 1]
#############
predictions:  [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
labels:       [1 0 1 1 1 2 0 2]
#############
predictions:  [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
labels:       [0 0 0 1 2 1 2 0]
#############
predictions:  [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
labels:       [2 0 2 0 1 1 0 2]
#############
predictions:  [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
labels:       [2 0 1 0 1 0 1 0]
#############
predictions:  [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
labels:       [1 0 1 2 2 1 0 1]
#############
predictions:  [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
labels:       [0 2 2 0 2 0 0 2]
#############
predictions:  [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
labels:       [0 1 1 1 1 0 0 0]
#############
predictions:  [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
labels:       [2 0 1 2 2 0 0 2]
#############
predictions:  [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
labels:       [1 0 1 2 0 0 1 1]
#############
predictions:  [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
labels:       [0 0 0 0 1 0 0 1]
#############
predictions:  [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
labels:       [2 1 2 1 1 2 2 2]
#############
predictions:  [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
labels:       [2 0 2 2 2 2 1 0]
#############
predictions:  [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
labels:       [2 2 2 2 1 0 0 2]
#############
predictions:  [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
labels:       [1 0 2 2 2 1 0 1]
#############
predictions:  [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
labels:       [0 1 0 0 1 0 2 1]
#############
predictions:  [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
labels:       [1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0]
#############
predictions:  [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
labels:       [1 2 1 2 0 2 1 2]
#############
predictions:  [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
labels:       [2 1 2 0 1 2 1 0]
#############
predictions:  [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
labels:       [2 2 2 0 0 0 1 2]
#############
predictions:  [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
labels:       [0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1]
#############
predictions:  [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
labels:       [2 2 0 1 1 2 2 1]
#############
predictions:  [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
labels:       [0 2 0 0 0 2 2 1]
#############
predictions:  [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
labels:       [2 1 2 1 1 1 2 2]
#############
predictions:  [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
labels:       [2 0 0 0 2 0 1 0]
#############
predictions:  [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
labels:       [1 1 2 1 0 2 2 0]
#############
predictions:  [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
labels:       [0 0 0 1 2 2 2 0]
#############
predictions:  [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
labels:       [1 0 0 0 2 1 1 2]
#############
predictions:  [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
labels:       [1 0 2 0 2 1 0 0]
#############
predictions:  [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
labels:       [1 1 0 2 0 0 1 0]
#############
predictions:  [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
labels:       [2 1 0 0 1 0 0 1]
#############
predictions:  [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
labels:       [2 2 2 2 0 0 1 0]
#############
predictions:  [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
labels:       [2 0 1 1 1 0 2 0]
#############
predictions:  [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
labels:       [0 1 1 2 2 1 2 1]
#############
predictions:  [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
labels:       [2 1 0 2 0 2 2 2]
#############
predictions:  [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
labels:       [0 0 0 1 1 0 1 0]
#############
predictions:  [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
labels:       [2 0 1 1 1 1 2 0]
#############
predictions:  [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
labels:       [1 0 2 1 0 0 0 0]
#############
predictions:  [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
labels:       [1 1 1 2 1 0 1 2]
#############
predictions:  [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
labels:       [2 0 2 2 0 0 0 0]
#############
predictions:  [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
labels:       [0 2 2 2 0 0 2 2]
#############
predictions:  [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
labels:       [0 1 0 2 2 2 1 2]
#############
predictions:  [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
labels:       [1 1 0 0 1 2 2 2]
#############
predictions:  [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
labels:       [0 0 1 2 0 1 2 2]
#############
predictions:  [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
labels:       [0 2 0 0 0 2 2 2]
#############
predictions:  [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
labels:       [0 2 1 2 0 2 0 0]
#############
predictions:  [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
labels:       [1 1 1 1 0 1 1 1]
#############
predictions:  [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
labels:       [1 2 0 1 0 0 0 1]
#############
predictions:  [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
labels:       [0 0 0 0 0 2 2 1]
#############
predictions:  [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
labels:       [0 1 1 1 2 0 1 0]
#############
predictions:  [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
labels:       [0 0 2 2 0 1 1 1]
#############
predictions:  [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
labels:       [0 0 2 0 1 1 2 1]
#############
predictions:  [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
labels:       [2 0 0 0 1 2 2 1]
#############
predictions:  [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
labels:       [0 0 2 1 2 0 1 1]
#############
predictions:  [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
labels:       [0 0 1 1 1 0 1 2]
#############
predictions:  [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
labels:       [1 1 1 1 2 0 0 2]
#############
predictions:  [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
labels:       [0 1 1 0 1 1 2 2]
#############
predictions:  [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
labels:       [1 2 0 2 1 0 2 0]
#############
predictions:  [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
labels:       [0 0 0 0 0 2 1 2]
#############
predictions:  [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
labels:       [2 0 0 1 2 2 1 2]
#############
predictions:  [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
labels:       [1 0 1 2 0 1 1 2]
#############
predictions:  [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
labels:       [0 2 2 1 0 2 1 1]
#############
predictions:  [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
labels:       [1 1 1 2 0 2 2 1]
#############
predictions:  [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
labels:       [1 0 1 2 2 2 0 1]
#############
predictions:  [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
labels:       [1 0 1 1 2 0 2 2]
#############
predictions:  [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
labels:       [0 2 0 1 1 0 2 2]
#############
predictions:  [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
labels:       [0 2 2 2 2 2 0 2]
#############
predictions:  [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
labels:       [1 1 0 0 0 1 0 2]
#############
predictions:  [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
labels:       [1 1 2 1 2 1 0 2]
#############
predictions:  [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
labels:       [2 1 0 0 0 2 2 1]
#############
predictions:  [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
labels:       [0 2 0 1 1 1 0 1]
#############
predictions:  [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
labels:       [2 1 1 0 2 2 2 2]
#############
predictions:  [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
labels:       [2 1 1 1 1 2 0 0]
#############
predictions:  [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
labels:       [0 0 2 0 1 0 2 0]
#############
predictions:  [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
labels:       [0 2 0 2 2 0 2 2]
#############
predictions:  [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
labels:       [0 0 1 2 2 2 1 2]
#############
predictions:  [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
labels:       [2 0 0 1 0 2 1 1]
#############
predictions:  [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
labels:       [0 2 2 1 0 2 0 1]
#############
predictions:  [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
labels:       [0 0 2 0 2 2 1 1]
#############
predictions:  [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
labels:       [0 2 0 0 1 0 1 1]
#############
predictions:  [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
labels:       [2 2 1 0 0 0 2 2]
#############
predictions:  [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
labels:       [1 2 0 1 2 1 0 0]
#############
predictions:  [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
labels:       [1 1 2 2 2 2 0 0]
#############
predictions:  [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
labels:       [1 0 0 1 2 0 2 1]
#############
predictions:  [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
labels:       [2 0 2 1 1 1 1 1]
#############
predictions:  [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
labels:       [1 1 0 0 0 1 0 1]
#############
predictions:  [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
labels:       [1 1 2 0 1 2 2 0]
#############
predictions:  [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
labels:       [0 1 1 1 2 1 0 0]
#############
predictions:  [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
labels:       [1 0 1 1 1 0 0 2]
#############
predictions:  [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
labels:       [2 2 0 0 0 0 1 0]
#############
predictions:  [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
labels:       [0 0 1 1 2 0 0 1]
#############
predictions:  [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
labels:       [2 1 1 1 0 1 0 0]
#############
predictions:  [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
labels:       [2 0 2 2 2 0 0 1]
#############
predictions:  [0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
labels:       [2 2 1 1 0 0 1]
#############
======Average Validation Loss: 1.09527======
======Average Validation Accuracy: 35.53%======
```

Comment: Try running this program on CPU.

Comment: How many epochs did you train? Is that dataset publicly available?

Comment: training on CPU has the same result

Comment: I make my own dataset publicly avaliable. and the other one is from kaggle:
https://www.kaggle.com/ankurzing/sentiment-analysis-for-financial-news

I trained only 1 epoch (as is the default setting in the simpletransformers library which brings great results). but higher epochs give the same result

Comment: I found out that in the training loop for some reason labels and sentences are mismatched. from what I can see this is not due to data pre-processing however

Comment: I put the wrong labels when initializing the dataset. that was causing the problem. i am still not getting a good accuracy just yet though

Comment: Make sure your batch data is what you expect it to be. Do `batch = next(iter(train_data_loader)` and then `print(batch)` to inspect what's in the batch.

Comment: @stackoverflowuser2010 thanks for your suggestion. everything looks fine. the labels match the sentences. attention mask and input_ids seem alright too. still the model tends to predict the most common class

Answer (score -3, accepted):

For multi-class classification/sentiment analysis using BERT the 'neutral' class HAS TO BE 2!! It CANNOT be between 'negative' = 0 and 'positive' = 2

Comment: I am pretty sure that this wasn't causing the issue.

Comment: then why does it work now after correcting the labels? and why did for example he do it like that too: https://www.kaggle.com/mastmustu/sentiment-analysis-using-bert-pytorch

I checked it first with toy examples from the huggingface guide. you can see for yourself. if you use 0,1,2 = negative, neutral, positive then even for toy examples the model starts to always predict one class

edit: btw I agree with you that its really weird. I dont understand why at this point. But I can assure you that after changing the labels it works correctly. You can test for yourself. The code is on my github

Comment: I don't think assigning the neutral class to be 2 is the fundamental fix. There is another problem.

Comment: yes, maybe. I could not find it though. If you have an idea what could be causing this I would be happy to hear it

Answer (score 0):

I want to leave an answer here for people that are struggling with a similar issue.

1. Try different learning rates. The learning rate is most likely too high, try to lower it. (Worked for me)
2. Reduce the number of Epochs while training. This problem is related to fine-tuning. If the dataset is extensive, 1-2 epochs may be enough.
3. Try out different batch sizes or introduce dropout layers.

For a lengthy discussion see: https://github.com/ThilinaRajapakse/simpletransformers/issues/234

Comment: The OP said that tuning parameters did not work.